# Model does not contain a definition for and no extension method

Tags: c#, linq

The database that I inherited has a LOT of poorly written stored procedures that I am not allowed to change because they are being used in other programs and there are too many to rewrite all of them.  I am trying to get rid of duplicates by using Linq GroupBy but I am getting the error that the "Model" does not contain a definintion for the field, which of course, it does.  I'm sure this is something simple that I am missing.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetIncidentColumns()
        {
            int questionClusterID = 25;
            var getcolumns = await CommonClient.GetIncidentColumnsForClusterID(questionClusterID);
            var columns = getcolumns.GroupBy(c => c).Select(grp => grp.IncidentColumnID).ToArray();
            return Json(columns, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Here is the model:

```
public class IncidentColumnsModel
    {
        public int IncidentTabulationID { get; set; }
        public int IncidentColumnID { get; set; }
        public string vchColumnReference { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ColumnNameID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> intSequence { get; set; }
        public string vchHeaderCssClass { get; set; }
        public string vchColumnHeaderText { get; set; }
        public string vchToolTip { get; set; }
        public string vchColumnCssClass { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> intHeaderRow { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> bitStartHeaderTextAboveColumn { get; set; }
        public string vchHeaderTextAboveColumn { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> intHeaderTextAboveColumnCount { get; set; }
        public string vchHeaderTextAboveColumnColor { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> intColumnPrecicion { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> intColumnScale { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> bitCalculatedColumn { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> bitAllowDataEntry { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> bitIncludeInSummaryRow { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> ColumnSummaryTypeID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> intFormulaNumeratorASeqNum { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> intFormulaNumeratorBSeqNum { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> intFormulaNumeratorCSeqNum { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> intFormulaNumeratorDSeqNum { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> intFormulaNumeratorESeqNum { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> decFormulaNumeratorMultiplier { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> bitThisIsARatio { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> intFormulaDenomeratorFSeqNum { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> intFormulaDenomeratorGSeqNum { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> intFormulaDenomeratorHSeqNum { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> intFormulaDenomeratorISeqNum { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> intFormulaDenomeratorJSeqNum { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> decFormulaDenomeratorMultiplier { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> bitFormulaValidate { get; set; }
        public string vchValidateOnFormulaText { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> intValidateGTESeqNum { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> decValidateGTEMultiplier { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> intValidateLTSeqNum { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> decValidateLTMultiplier { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> bitRangeValidate { get; set; }
        public string vchValidateOnRangeText { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> decRangeValidGTE { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> decRangeValidLT { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> bitRequiredField { get; set; }
        public string vchAssociatedDetailColumn { get; set; }
        public string vchAssociatedSummaryColumn { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> intColumnPositionFromLeft { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> intValidateGTESeqNumB { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> intValidateGTESeqNumC { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> intValidateLTSeqNumB { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> intValidateLTSeqNumC { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> bitRolling12MonthCalculation { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> bitRolling4QuarterCalculation { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> intSummaryFormulaNumeratorASeqNum { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> intSummaryFormulaNumeratorBSeqNum { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> intSummaryFormulaNumeratorCSeqNum { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> intSummaryFormulaNumeratorDSeqNum { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> intSummaryFormulaNumeratorESeqNum { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> decSummaryFormulaNumeratorMultiplier { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> bitSummaryThisIsARatio { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> intSummaryFormulaDenomeratorFSeqNum { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> intSummaryFormulaDenomeratorGSeqNum { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> intSummaryFormulaDenomeratorHSeqNum { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> intSummaryFormulaDenomeratorISeqNum { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> intSummaryFormulaDenomeratorJSeqNum { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> decSummaryFormulaDenomeratorMultiplier { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need only one column which is ID so you should be grouping on  `IncidentColumnID` and then project it on `IncidentColumnID` by writing:

```
var columns = getcolumns.GroupBy(c => c.IncidentColumnID)
                        .Select(grp => grp.First())
                        .ToArray();
```

Comment: This did stop the error and it did get rid of the duplicates, but all it returns is the key field and NONE of the other fields.

Comment: you need to project further for that

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean,

Comment: That did it.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

.[GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb534501(v=vs.100).aspx)() returns an object of type `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>`.

Does IGrouping having a property called `IncidentColumnID`?